# Test java application on physical devise using Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have the latest version of Kies installed and the official USB driver for the Galaxy S4 installed. I'm running genuine Windows 7.

Though I can launch the software emulator from inside Eclipse Juno with no problems at all, I cannot test my applications on my physical Galaxy.

When clicking on run, I can see my device. but that's it. The "ok" button is greyed out. Something to do with the 'unknown' target I'd wager.

[image: unknown target devise Eclipse]

All help appreciated!

Comment: Have you configured your device to be able to install applications without be uploaded to Google Play?

Comment: Nope, I'm a real beginner in this field! I've enabled developer options and checked "usb debugging" on the device. Where do I allow applications to be installed?

Comment: In my device, you must to follow this steps:

Menu > Settings > Applications

and check unknow sources